# check if all checkbox are unchecked on cypress

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress

I have dynamic checkboxes (anything from 1-20 checkboxes). I want to check if all checkboxes are unchecked.

I have tried serval ways without any success.

```
//is true even if it is checked
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').not("checked");

cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').should('have.attr', 'checked', false)
```

Comment: A sample of your checkboxes HTML will help.

Answer (score 3):

The `checked` attribute does not have a true/false value. It's either present or absent.

This should work:

```js
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').should('not.be.checked')        // checks multiple
```

Comment: How could we use this in situations when there just several checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is coming from the fact that your `.get()` should yield multiple checkboxes, but you're then using a singular assert on it. Switching to using `.each()` to iterate through each yielded checkbox should work better.

```js
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').each(($el) => {
  cy.wrap($el).should('have.attr', 'checked', false)
});
```

Comment: I still getting error `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<input#checkbox-d585d504-bc32-495c-807e-cd5f6dc83652.checkbox__input>' to have attribute 'checked'` it seems it is trying to find checked, but in my case I dont want any attributes to have checked. It seems the false doesn’t work as expected

Comment: Ah, so the issue is probably related to how you're checking that it is checked. Can you try `.should('not.have.attr', 'checked')`?